# Flutter rest api all my data is showing null

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I am learning to use api and all data in my interface is showing as null

in this section to understand where the problem lies i change ! with ?

How can I check if there is a problem while pulling the data?

I deleted the irrelevant parts to shorten the code.

```
  WeatherApiClient client = WeatherApiClient();
  Hava? data;

  Future<void> getData()async{
    data = await client.getCurrentWeather("London");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(  
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.done){
              return Column(
                children: [
                  GuncelVeri(Icons.wb_sunny_rounded, "${data?.derece}", "${data?.sehir}"),
                  bilgiler("${data?.humidity}","${data?.feels_like}", "${data?.pressure}","${data?.description}"),],
              );

            }
            else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return Container();
          },
        )

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:weatherapp/model.dart';

class WeatherApiClient{
  Future<Hava>? getCurrentWeather(String? location)async{
    var endpoint = Uri.parse(
      "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$location&appid=9b6ece44d1233c111b86cacb5e3617f1&units=metric&lang=tr"
    );
    var response = await http.get(endpoint);
    var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(Hava.fromJson(body));
    return Hava.fromJson(body);
}
}
```

Comment: first try to `print(body)` to see wether the response is null or not

Comment: user exception handling methods like try catch

Answer (score 1):

> Your are getting Null because you are trying to access the Hava class which have not been initilized yet.

You are printing `print(Hava.fromJson(body));`
before `return Hava.fromJson(body);`

First you want to check if what responce is getting from the http call.

*for that you can just print the http responce like this:-*

`print(responce.body)`

Then you can see what's the responce is.

They you can do `return Hava.fromJson(body);`

**The right way**

*Check the status code of the responce, if the responce is 200 the cast the json responce to the model class or show an error*

**Refer code**

```
Future<Profileclass> fetchprofile() async {
  String tokenFetch = await getStringValuesSF();

  return await Dio()
      .get(urlprofiledio,
          options: Options(
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer $tokenFetch',
            },
          ))
      .then((response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Profileclass.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.toString()));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load profile');
    }
  });
}
```

*Thank you*

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is in my album class. I defined the variable type incorrectly.